# show multiple origin and destination routes in ONE map using React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to show different origin and destination,but it's showing one only.In this code origin and destination are in array and loop an array dynamically it takes only one index info.

```
render(){  
let DirectionsComponent;
    if(this.state.trackData.length>0){
      debugger
        console.log(this.state.trackData)
        const da = this.state.trackData
            DirectionsComponent = compose(
                withProps({
                    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=",
                    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
                    containerElement: <div style={{ width: `100%` }} />,
                    mapElement: <div style={{height: `600px`, width: `600px` }}  />,
                }),
                withScriptjs,
                withGoogleMap,
                lifecycle({
                    componentDidMount(){
                      debugger
                      console.log(da.length)
                        for(let i=0;i<da.length;i++){
                            const waypoints = da[i].map(p=>({
                                location: {lat: parseFloat(p.PositionLat), lng:parseFloat(p.PositionLong)},
                                stopover: true
                            }))
                            const origin = waypoints.shift().location
                            const destination = waypoints.pop().location
                            const DirectionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
                            DirectionsService.route({
                                origin: origin,
                                destination: destination,
                                travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                                waypoints: waypoints
                            },(result, status) =>{
                                if (status === window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                                    this.setState({
                                        directions: {...result},
                                        markers: true,
                                    })
                                }else{
                                    console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
            )(props=>
            <GoogleMap defaultZoom={20} >{props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions}
            // suppressMarkers={props.markers}
            />
                }
            </GoogleMap>);
    }
```

sorry for my english and thank you